# How to detect covering graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, covering-spaces

Let's say $G$ is a graph. How can we detect if $G$ is (nontrivially) a [covering graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_graph)?

$G$ is nontrivial covering graph if there is a covering map $f : G \to C $ (for some graph $C$) such that $f$ is not an isomorphism.

It would be best, in particular, if the algorithm gave a way of constructing a function $f$ that matches the above criteria.

Comment: What kind of "maps" are allowed? What does "detect" mean? You can "detect" by looking at the degree distribution, or other local statistics.  For a covering graph, the degrees should be repeated with common multiplicity.  This kind of screening will throw out many graphs right from the beginning (100% specificity), but of course it will leave some graphs that are not covering graphs (sensitivity below 100%).

Comment: @jarauh any covering map that isn't an isomorphism. 100% prediction is sort of the idea, maybe in the form of a forbidden minor characterization.

Comment: Forbidden minors is not possible.  I would guess that any graph is the image of a nontriviel covering map.

Comment: This is true. Just take two disjoint copies of the original graph.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the fibres of a covering map give an equitable partition of G with parts of all the same size. So your graph will have to have such an equitable partition (other than the trivial one). Furthermore, the quotient matrix of this equitable partition will have to be 01-valued. But at this point we are probably just rephrasing the definition of a covering graph.

Comment: @jarauh If we are assuming covering graphs are connected, then this not not true -- a tree is not the image of a nontrivial graph covering, because it does not have any nontrivial (connected) cover as a topological space.

Comment: @HarryRichman This is true, interesting observation. On the other hand, it is hard to detect if something is a tree by looking at "small" minors.

Answer (score 1):

This is far from an algorithm, but maybe gives some idea how to look for such an $f$ in particular cases.

Since covering maps of graphs are also coverings in the sense of topology (although far more restrictive), one restriction would be to look at the Euler characteristic of the underlying topological space of the graph, i.e. $\chi(G) = |V| -|E|$.

Assume $\chi(G) \neq 0$. If $f:G \rightarrow C$ is a covering of degree $d$, then  $\chi(G) = d \chi(C)$, and so $d$ is a factor of $\chi(G)$. So I guess, the first thing to look at is the prime decomposition of $\chi(G)$.

If the Euler characteristic is divisible by $d>0$. Then one further restriction is to check if the number of vertices with each given degree is divisible by $d$.

Comment: This could be extended to a deterministic algorithm in a dumb way -- for any divisor $d$ of $\chi(G)$, there are finitely many graphs $H$ with the appropriate number of vertices and edges to admit a $d$-fold cover $G\to H$. And for each $H$ there are finitely many maps from $G$. So we could check these one by one by exhaustive search, in theory.

Comment: Another big restriction is that the covering degree $d$ must divide both $|V|$ and $|E|$, so even when $\chi(G) = 0$ we have a finite list possible $d$ to check.